# Excel not extracting table of historical stock prices from Yahoo Finance

Tags: excel, vba, yahoo-finance

I'm attempting to extract a table of historical stock prices to bring into a an Excel worksheet. I'm currently using Excel for Mac so activex / com objects are not supported, which is why I have had to go this route. If I use a different URL it extracts the table information just fine, and visiting the URL directly in browser works fine, but if I try to extract historical price information Excel throws a VB error 1004.

```
HistoryURL = "URL:https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/history?period1=1577836800&period2=1609459200&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d&includeAdjustedClose=true"
        
With .QueryTables.Add(Connection:=HistoryURL, Destination:=.Range("Z1"))
             .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
             .PreserveFormatting = True
             .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
             .BackgroundQuery = True
             .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
             .SavePassword = False
             .SaveData = False
        End With
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't find a suitable way to do this with VBA so I enabled the Beta Channel updates for Excel which allowed me to start using the native StockHistory function.

Answer (score 0):

I've done a bit of work with finnancial data/stock price data and I found the following API a lot easier to work with than yahoo's finance data. You can get historical stock price data, so feel free to check it out and see if it might work for your application.  [Finnancial API](https://financialmodelingprep.com/developer/docs/)